# Mark-up for desktop and separate mobile version of site, can they be used cross domain?

Tags: canonical-url, mobile, multiple-domains, markup, rel-alternate

When there is a separate mobile version of a site on a different URL to the main site, Google suggests to use their [Annotations for desktop and mobile URLs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details).

> On the desktop page, add:
>
> ```
> <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
>       href="http://m.example.com/page-1" >
> ```
>
> and on the mobile page, the required annotation should be:
>
> ```
> <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page-1" >
> ```

Can these be used cross domain?

e.g:

Desktop site: www.example.com

Mobile site on a different domain: www.example.mobile

I know this is the possibly the worst way to set up a mobile version of a site, but say in a worst case scenario, could they work?

I'm thinking most likely not, however canonical tags can be used cross domain, so in theory it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, cross-domain is fine. Using .mobi was very popular for a while, other sites just use "m.theirdomain.com", it's essentially up to you. Keep in mind that multiple domains for the same site does increase the maintenance overhead, but that's ultimately your decision.